# Updating to Ubuntu 22.04 Crashed theSystem

Tags: dual-boot, updates, crash, 22.04

[image]I got the notification that there was an update to 22.04 available and I chose to update it. It was done downloading the files and was 15% done with installing when it suddenly crashed. It displayed an image which says that the system crashed and I need to contact an administrator.

I tried opening Ubuntu using recovery mode and the same image showed up. Also I'm dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10, in case that is important.

Edit: Added the image

Comment: Can you take a photo of that screen…? Usually you either get a rescue prompt of if something is really broken a kernel panic

Comment: @cocomac Added image. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: I am having the same issue. What is a good way to debug this?